# SQL error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query controller

```
$query = $this->subtaskModel->getUserQuerysprint($user['id']);
```

and model query

```
public function getUserQuerysprint() 
{
    return $this->db->table("select * from sprint");
}
```

I got an error

> amInternal Error: SQL error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'select * from sprint' at line 1

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which database wrapper are you using?

Comment: @catcon thanks for yoyr comment using pdo

Comment: what is "$this->db" (type)? it looks like `table(..)` is expecting a table name rather than a query.

Comment: That's not PDO, it's a wrapper. You'll need to show more than these few lines before we can tell you what's wrong without guessing..

Comment: @Qirel its [db:protected] => PicoDb\Database Object i am new to this please help me

Comment: By looking at the doc, you execute `table()` is used for selecting a table, if you want to execute a query use `execute()`. Read more about it here: https://github.com/elvanto/picodb

Answer (score 0):

please add more details about this because it's very hard with little information/details. but could you try this.

```
return $this->db->table("select * from `sprint`");
```